# Filtered comparison in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following format:

```
ID,FLAG,PERIOD
4,"C",7/19/2017
4,"C",7/22/2017
4,"R",7/22/2017
4,"R",7/26/2017
```

data:

```
with temp as (
        select 4 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/26/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual union
        select 4 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual union
        select 4 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual union 
        select 4 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/19/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual)
```

I would like to have a result which indicates the `ID`, and whether the `max(Period)` where the flag is "C" for this `ID` is greater than the respective `max(Period)` where the flag is "R".

My desired result would be (Since the max(Period) for C here is 22/7/2017 and the max(Period) for R is 26/07/2017:

```
ID  IS_GREATER
4   NO
```

I have thought about making a group by query with ID and Flag and max(Period) and then doing a case statement. As I am new to this, I was wondering is there a better way?

Comment: Do you always have at least one C and one R for a given ID  ?  if not, what is the expected behaviour ? Yes if you have a C and no R and no otherwise ?

Comment: I don't really care about those cases, NO or blank would be both fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with temp
     as (select 4 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/26/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 4 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 4 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 4 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/19/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 5 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/26/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 5 as ID, 'R' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 5 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/22/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual
         union
         select 5 as ID, 'C' as Flag, to_date('07/19/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Period from dual)
  select ID
       , case
           when max(case when FLAG = 'C' then Period else null end) > max(case when FLAG = 'R' then Period else null end) then
             'Y'
           else
             'N'
         end
           is_greater
    from temp
group by ID;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)